# Access to current instance State Vue

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I am trying to access to currents errors store data from Vue but i have not the expected result

```
console.log(store.state.auth.errors); // null
```

When i review the complete log with

```
console.log(store.state.auth)
```

[image]

The info that i want is allowed in a proxy target object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail I can only guess.

My guess is that it's just a matter of timing. What's likely happening is that where you are trying to get the contents of `store.state.auth.errors`, the value is still null. But when you log `store.state.auth` it returns a Proxy which stays up to date in the dev tools. So when you expand the content of the Proxy, it has already been set.

#### How to validate

If you capture the current value `console.log(JSON.stringify(store.state.auth,null,2))` you can see value logged at the time when the console log is called.

#### How to deal with it

This will depend on what exactly is going on with the rest of your code. If you are relying on an API call, use the `then`/`catch` to deal with it. you can also use a `watch` or `computed` to track the changes if you want to map it to a method call or an error message.